# My VBS code just doesn't work

Tags: vbscript

I was trying to do some coding in VBScript and I've got an error, but I don't know what is wrong.

```
a = InputBox("Enter Numerator")
b = InputBox("Enter Denominator")

If b = 0 Then
  MsgBox "b is 0 , that's not right probably, I'll set  b=1"
  b = 1

MgBox "Contribution" & a & ":" & b & "=" & MojeDeleni(a, b)

Function MySplitting(a,b)
  On Error Resume Next
  MySplitting = a/b
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MySplitting = "Splitting error no." & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description
  End if
  Err.Clear
End Function
```

Comment: What is `MoejeDeleni` in your code? Is it a function?

Comment: Please *show* the error you're getting. Also, there's a typo in line 9 (`MgBox "Contribution" ...`), and your first `If` is probably missing an `End If`.

Comment: Changed End If and MgBox to MsgBox and still error, im from Czech so my error message wont probably help you

Comment: Please tell what is the value of the variable `MojeDeleni`?

Comment: You seems to mean `MySplitting` from it (English)?

Comment: Yes, MySplitting

Comment: What. Is. The. Error?

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos in your code.

```vbs
If B = "" Then '<< String CANNOT BE Integer, YOU SHOULD USE "" TO CHECK IF IT IS EMPTY >>
  MsgBox "Denominator is 0, That's not right probably, I'll set Denominator to 1"
  B = 1
End If '<< End If IS MISSING HERE >>
```

Or you can use `If CInt(B) = 0 Then`.

```vbs
Function MySplitting(A, B)
   On Error Resume Next
   MySplitting = CInt(A) / CInt(B)
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MySplitting = "Splitting Error : " & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & 
Err.Description
   End If
   Err.Clear
End Function

MgBox "Contribution" & A & " : " & B & " = " & MojeDeleni(A, B) '<< HERE MgBox SHOULD BE MsgBox >>
```

If you assigned a new variable with one language and want to use it with another language, it is not possible to do unless you tell scripting engine they are same variables like below.

```vbs
MojeDeleni = MySplitting(A, B)
```

So now following should work.

```vbs
MsgBox "Contribution is " & A & " : " & B & " = " & MojeDeleni
```

To prevent your message "Contribution" from displaying when any error happens, you can do the following:

```vbs
MojeDeleni = MySplitting(A, B)

If InStr(Result, "Error") = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Contribution is " & A & " : " & B & " = " & MojeDeleni
Else
  MsgBox MojeDeleni
End If
```